# Connecting GWT and PostgreSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, postgresql, gwt

I've been working with GWT and appengine. Now I want to change my database to a relational one. I prefer PostgreSQL over MySQL because of the schema architecture.

I already work in projects with JDBC, but I cannot make it work in my appengine project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is really about Google App Engine, rather than GWT, so re-tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistake. If you want your backend to connect to JDBC you have to disable appengine.

I recommend creating a new web project with the google eclipse plugin but without appengine. Then copy all the source files and start from there.

I let you my class to connect to PostgreSQL vua JDBC

```
public class ConexionBD
{
    private Vector <Connection> connections = new Vector<Connection>();

    protected int cantCon=3;
    private static ConexionBD pool;
    private ConexionBD(){


        for (int i= 0; i< cantCon;i++)
            connections.add(connect());
    }


    public static ConexionBD getPoolConnection(){
        if (pool== null)
            pool =new ConexionBD();
        return pool;
    }
    private Connection connect()
    {
        try
        {
            //Setear driver
            Class.forName ("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance ();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/llevomisnegocios","postgres","root");

            return con;
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Mensaje Error al Conectar: " + e.getMessage());
            //System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Mensaje Error al Conectar: " + ex.getMessage());
            //System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + ex.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void closeConnections(){
        for (int i=0; i<connections.size();i++)
        {
            try
            {
                connections.elementAt(i).close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Mensaje Error: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
    public  Connection getConnection(){
        Connection c = null;
        if (connections.size()>0)
            c = connections.remove(0);
        else{
            c = connect();
            System.out.println("PoolConnection: Conexion Exitosa con la BD");
        }
        return c;
    }
    public void realeaseConnection(Connection c){
        connections.add(c);
    }




}
```